# -OutVariable does not work on Get-DistributionGroup or Get-DistributionGroupMember

Tags: powershell

I'm using ExchangeOnlineManagement version 2.0.4 and I've stumbled across an issue with the `-OutVariable` parameter of `Get-DistributionGroup` and `Get-DistributionGroupMember`. I've tested on several machines and the issue exists on each. I haven't found any relevant information online but before opening an issue. I'd like to confirm if others suffer the same affliction.

Environment information

```
Get-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     2.0.4      ExchangeOnlineManagement            {Get-EXOCasMailbox, Get-EXOMailbox, Get-EXOMailboxFolderPe...


$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.1171
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.1171
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

If I were to file an issue, I'm not sure if I would file it on the main Powershell\Powershell repo or another (that I've yet to find.) The PSGallery page for [this module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ExchangeOnlineManagement/2.0.4) unfortunately doesn't have a link to a project.

Some examples that demonstrate the issue

**Example 1**

```
Get-DistributionGroup -OutVariable groups

$groups  # empty!
```

**Example 2**

```
$groups = Get-DistributionGroup

$groups.id | Get-DistributionGroupMember -OutVariable members

$members # nada!
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: I don't have o365, but out of curiosity I tried this in my 2013 onPrem environment. Looks like `-OutVariable` just doesn't work!  In my case the members get echoed from the `Get-DistributionGroupMember` command itself, but the variable isn't present or populated.  Not to excuse the obvious problem, but why not just put the variable on the left side of an assignment statement?

Comment: As you can see in my second example, we can do just that. Could also use Tee-Object. However this being a powershell common parameter, feel like this is an issue worth looking into.

Comment: Oh no argument there it should work.  Apologies for the confusion, mostly wanted you to know seems a problem onPrem as well.

Comment: Sorry if I came off as defensive. I definitely didn’t mean to and appreciate the time you took to test and comment. What I really want to know is under what circumstances does a common parameter not work? Good to know it’s not just the exonline module. I didn’t even think to check an on prem environment.

Comment: NP, I didn't take it that way.  I have slight hunch it has something to do with restricted or other language modes. Which in an Exchange remote scenario are defined in the backend web.config file.  However, my understanding of this is too murky. I mean considering the ESM obviously doesn't have many other restrictions from restricted language mode...